# Where to store design documents for CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB and I wonder how experienced CouchDB handles the large amount of design documents.

My questions:

1. Where do you store design documents: In CouchDB with Futon's "save" or on harddrive then uploading it through the HTTP API?
2. If you are uploading them, how do you do it? You create custom queries or are you using any framework?
3. I'm using node.js, are there good libraries/frameworks that I could use to ease the CouchDB development?

Please share your experiences!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Since the whole of CouchDB works through a REST API, all Futon is doing really is working through the REST interface. Basically, you will always load it through the HTTP API. It's a matter of choice of which tool you will do it with, in which the tool abstracts the process for you. At the end of the day, all a design document is, is another type of document.

2) Personally, since I am coding for it in python, I use the couchdbkit framework, which has auto document loading on it. I am sure there is something similar for node.js. I am unable to answer though.

3) Maybe [node-couchdb](https://github.com/felixge/node-couchdb), although it seems to be no longer maintained. There is alot of material on the internet, just google it!

Answer (score 1):

CouchApp is the best tool for managing/uploading your design docs. Its main purpose is for pure Couch apps but you dont have to use that aspect, it makes design doc managing a breeze (couchapp push).

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB is JSON over HTTP, both things Node does more or less natively. I've found the npm module [Nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano/) to work fairly well.

As far as CouchApp goes, there's a [couchapp for node](https://github.com/mikeal/node.couchapp.js).